# Deploying a Smart Contract

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, cryptocurrency

If I were to deploy a smart contract for NFT's that I would want to sell which is the best way to do this. And is utilising Injected Web3 on Remix.ethereum.org an acctual option.

Answer (score 1):

Also, if you have a large NFT project, it will only be realistically possible to deploy large amounts of NFTs using scripts in a solidity development framework.

Answer (score 0):

If your deployment process simple, Remix IDE's [injected web3](https://remix-ide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/create_deploy.html#deploy-the-contract) is a viable option.

If you need to run deployment scripts, for example to mint after deployment, run some test transactions, share your contract address on twitter(?) than frameworks such as [hardhat](https://hardhat.org/guides/deploying.html) are really useful. Because you can create complex deployment scripts with them. For hardhat, that is a JS file.

You can also do it with your bare hands. Compile your code with `solc`, get the bytecode maybe get the ABI too, send a transaction to the empty address putting your bytecode as data and have a contract on blockchain.

Comment: so what you are saying is depending on the project and it's needs both options are a possibility ?

Comment: exactly, depends on the complexity and needs